# Order search results by category

Tags: search, order

I'm using this code to order my search results by post type and title, but I would like to order by category too. How can I do it?

```
add_filter('posts_orderby','my_sort_custom',10,2);
function my_sort_custom( $orderby, $query ){
    global $wpdb;
    if(!is_admin() && is_search()) 
        $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix."posts.post_type ASC, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_title DESC";

    return  $orderby;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled over this looking myself for a solution to order posts from `WP_Query` by their related terms, which seems to be the quintessence of this question. (I'll answer to the special search case of the question below the general description.)

## Sorting Posts by related Terms

So the key is the MySQL function `FIELD()` which allows to solve these problem by attaching only one filter to `posts_orderby` in combination with the use of `tax_query`.

Using the `tax_query` parameter of `WP_Query` is necessary, to »JOIN« `wp_posts` table with `wp_term_relationships` whose column `term_taxonomy_id` we want to order by.

If it is not wanted to queue for specific terms, just pass all terms as value:

```
# get all terms of 'category' ordered by the terms name (default behaviour)
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
$query_args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $terms
        )
    )
);

/**
 * the filter callback
 * removes itself from the applied filter
 *
 * @wp-hook posts_orderby
 * @param string $sql (Default oderby clause)
 * @param WP_Query $query
 * @uses $terms which are allready in the correct order
 * @return string
 */
$orderby_terms = function( $sql, $query ) use ( $terms, &$orderby_terms ) {
    $field = $GLOBALS[ 'wpdb' ]->term_relationships . '.term_taxonomy_id';
    $terms = array_map( 'intval', $terms );
    $sql = sprintf(
        'FIELD( %1$s, %2$s ) ',
        $field,
        implode( ', ', $terms )
    );
    remove_filter( current_filter(), $orderby_terms );

    return $sql;
};
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', $orderby_terms, 10, 2 );
$query = new \WP_Query( $query_args );
```

To answer the question more detailed: as you need the `tax_query` parameter

### Limitations

- This Query won't fetch posts, which aren't assigned to any term. That's relevant for other taxonomies than `category`.
- In case a post is assigned to many terms, the sorting might not be as comprehensible as you would expect, because for each post only one term-relationship is considered (GROUP By clause in the SQL).

## Special Case: Search Queries

The way described above can be applied to the default search query as follows: 
You hook into `pre_get_posts` and make sure it's the main search query.

```
function wpse_91993_order_search( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() && ! $query->is_search() )
        return;

    $terms = get_terms( 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    $tax_query_args = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $terms
        )
    );
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query_args );

    /**
     * the filte callback
     * removes itself from the applied filter
     *
     * @wp-hook posts_orderby
     * @param string $sql (Default oderby clause)
     * @param WP_Query $query
     * @uses $terms which are allready in the correct order
     * @return string
     */
    $orderby_terms = function( $sql, $query ) use ( $terms, &$orderby_terms ) {
        $field = $GLOBALS[ 'wpdb' ]->term_relationships . '.term_taxonomy_id';
        $terms = array_map( 'intval', $terms );
        $sql = sprintf(
            'FIELD( %1$s, %2$s ) ',
            $field,
            implode( ', ', $terms )
        );
        remove_filter( current_filter(), $orderby_terms );

        return $sql;
    };
    add_filter( 'posts_orderby', $orderby_terms, 10, 2 );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\wpse_91993_order_search' );
```

**But that will ignore pages and attachments which are considered by default in the WordPress search query.** Usually there aren't even registered for the taxonomy `category`. At this point a proper solution depends on some decisions you need to make:

- Is it possible to register the taxonomy `category` to the post types `page` and `attachment` and make sure these posts get linked to at least the default term?
- Split your search in two queries, one for posts as shown above and one for pages and attachments and present the results separately in your theme?
- Is it worth the huge effort to change the SQL-Request to merge a selection on pages and attachments and a selection on posts ordered by terms? (I'm not even sure it is possible).